# Stata-related graphic enquiry

Tags: graph, stata

I have a very basic question about Stata. I have a repeated cross section of individuals from year 1 to year 20. For each individual, by year, I have a year-specific variable- GDP per capita in the country for instance. This variable is defined for each individual for each year, across years. I therefore have 20 unique data points for this variable. I want to plot this variable as a function of time (say in a two-way plot). The twoway command does not work because I have a lot more than 20 points for this 20 values because for each value I have it defined over the n  number of people in the cross section in that year. How can I create a separate variable that extracts only the distinct values from the variable in its current form?

Comment: This lacks even a minimal example with data and/or code you tried. Reading it twice doesn't give me even a rough picture of what the data are like or the kind of problem that arises. Please rewrite or delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a simple example of your data you could have saved yourself and others time. As it stands, your question is difficult to understand. As already pointed out, it lacks both code and example data. Please rewrite so others can easily find and use whatever is posted here.

My interpretation is you have panel data. The variable `gdp` is year-specific (in every panel the information is duplicated), but you'd like to graph it against time. Just tag one instance, and draw a graph conditional on that. An example:

```
clear
set more off

// not 20 years, but 3
input ///
id year gdp
1 1990 78
1 1991 90
1 1992 98
2 1990 78
2 1991 90
2 1992 98
end

egen tograph = tag(year)
twoway line gdp year if tograph
```

or

```
twoway line gdp year if id == 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect case of panel data:

First set the panel. The command to set the panel in your case is the following:

```
xtset id year
```

you can plot using `xtline` function using following command:

```
xtline gdp , t(year) i(id)
```

The above command will plot individual graphs for each id over year. To get one graph for all for comparison, use the following command:

```
xtline gdb , overlay t(year) i(id)
```